# Google Spreadsheets. Extract a list of email addresses that are in a sheet

Tags: function, spreadsheet, lookup

In Google Spreadsheets. I have a large sheet containing lots of bookings, a booking has several columns for name, voucher number, email address etc.  Each date I have a class on covers several columns and rows.   I want to build a single vertical list of every email address in the sheet.  The email addresses are in different columns and different rows.  I was thinking FILTER or LOOKUP but I can't quite find the answer that works.

```
Dec 17th 2-5            
Name    Voucher Email           People  
Richa   yes     richa@xx.ca     2  
Jessica yes     jess@sss.com    3  
Beth    cash    ebeth@hh.com    2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export your sheet as a CSV file (File > Download as ..)

Then use the REGEX tool of your choice (Notepad++) or some of the online tools available (first hit: http://emailregex.com/email-extractor-tool/).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `flatten()` to get all the data in a single column and use `regexextract(Cell or range,"[a-zA-Z]+@[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+")`